# Want to duplicate rows in a SQL view

Tags: sql

I have a `reservations` table containing reservations, such as:

```
       date      beg      end
------------  -------  -------
'2016-06-02'  '09:00'  '12:00'
'2016-06-03'  '14:00'  '17:00'
'2016-06-04'  '09:00'  '17:00'
```

and I need to convert it into a view such as:

```
       date      beg      end    tod
------------  -------  -------  ----
'2016-06-02'  '09:00'  '12:00'  'AM'
'2016-06-03'  '14:00'  '17:00'  'PM'
'2016-06-04'  '09:00'  '17:00'  'AM'
'2016-06-04'  '09:00'  '17:00'  'PM'
```

where the added column is the `tod` (for time of day), and -- that's the difficult part -- contains duplicates for reservations spanning over full days.

**NOTE -** A reservation beginning before 13:00 is considered AM only. A reservation ending after 13:00 is considered PM only. A reservation beginning before 13:00 and ending after 13:00 is considered both AM and PM, reason why the rows must be duplicated.

I've tried thinking at `JOIN` commands in order to be able to get the "multiplying factor", but the join condition `ON` is mandatory, and I don't see what it could be, nor the structure of the dummy table I should merge with.

Any tip to help me go on with this task?  Thanks!

Comment: UNION ALL is the way to go.

Comment: Couldn't you just put AM/PM in the TOD column? It would make a bit more sense.

Comment: No, because filters are applied on the table, and all AM reservations must be counted, and idem for PM reservations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an odd requirement, but `union all` seems like the way to go:

```
select date, beg, end, 'AM' as tod
from reservations r
where beg < '13:00'
union all
select date, beg, end, 'PM' as tod
from reservations r
where end >= '13:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.v
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id, 'AM' AS v UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'PM') AS t2
ON IF(t1.`beg` < '13:00', 'AM', 'PM') = t2.v OR
   IF(t1.`end` < '13:00', 'AM', 'PM') = t2.v
ORDER BY t1.`date`, t2.id
```

The above query uses an inline table:

```
 id   v
----+----
 1  | AM
----+----
 2  | PM
----+----
```

The `ON` predicates essentially *duplicate* rows beginning before `13:00` and ending after `13:00`.

Comment: Thanks as well for teaching me about the use of conditions in the `ON` clause!

Answer (score 0):

You can "multiply" rows by joining to a table of constants:

```
select *
from T
cross apply (
 select *
 from values ((1), (2)) x(number)
) x
```

This doubles all rows. You can very flexibly use this pattern. For example, you can use computed values inside of the cross apply or you can reduce the number of variable rows by adding a `where` to the cross apply.

The `union all` solution by Gordon also works. It causes different query plans.